# Как исключить scaling cx и cy аттрибутов при скейлинге circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Всем привет! Такая проблема. При применении `transform:scale()` на svg объект `circle`, scale так же применяется к `cx cy` аттрибутам. Мне нужно добится scale эффекта только на размер элемента. Вот примеры.

Как есть: [image: первый]

Как должно быть: [image: второй]

Сразу говорю, `transform-origin: center` не подходит(хотя в "как должно быть я его и использую") и `viewBox` тоже.

Само центрирование происходит потём установки `cx: 50%` `cy: 50%`, но, как я уже говорил при `transform:scale()` выходные значения уменьшаются.

Comment: @Alexandr_T я уж пол года назад решил эту проблему, но не помню особо как :) Но ваш ответ тоже подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@David Arutiunian, как я понял из вопроса, нужно, чтобы во время анимации координаты центра окружности **cx**, **cy** не изменялись, а радиус окружности **r** должен увеличиваться. Могу предложить вариант с использованием SMIL анимации.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">  
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="gold"/>
   <circle  id="circl" cx="150" cy="150" r="30" fill="dodgerblue" stroke-width="3" stroke="blue" >
  <animate attributeName="r"  dur="20s" begin="0.25s"
 values="30;150;30" repeatCount="indefinite"  feel="freeze" />
 </circle>
</svg>
```

В примере уменьшение и увеличение. Если нужно только увеличение радиуса окружности измените значение на следующее - **values="30;150"**

Вообще поиграйтесь с атрибутами анимации, чтобы увеличить скорость анимации, уменьшите значение **dur="10s"**

Если нужен только один цикл анимации - **repeatCount="1"**

Добавить этот SVG файл в HTML лучше через **object**

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="circle.svg" width="300" height="300">
  <img src="circle.png" width="300" height="300" alt="image format png" />
</object>
```

Можно усложнить немного пример - при наведении курсора окружность будет увеличиваться, при щелчке будет уменьшаться

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">  
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellowgreen"/>
   <circle  id="circl" cx="75" cy="75" r="15" fill="#9C27B0" stroke-width="2" stroke="#53155E" >
  <animate id="inc" attributeName="r"  dur="3s" begin="circl.mouseover"
        values="15;74" repeatCount="1"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       <animate attributeName="r"  dur="3s" begin="circl.click"
            values="74;15" repeatCount="1"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
 
 </circle>
</svg>
```